# What is the C# equivalent of java.util.function.Supplier?

Tags: java, c#

In Java, the `Supplier` interface represents a function with no arguments and a generic return value.

```java
Supplier<String> randomPasswordSupplier = () -> "secret";
String randomPassword = randomPasswordSupplier.get();
```

Is there an equivalent of this interface in C#?

Comment: [`Func<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1)

Comment: also relevant Consumer -> Action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449343/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-8-java-util-function-consumer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# (and maybe other languages) this is a [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), a delegate is a reference to methods with a particular parameter list and return type

> a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type

You can define your own delegates like so:

```
public delegate int Answer();
```

(This often used when declaring event handlers)

Alone this does nothing, but you can then use it like any other type to pass references to methods around, like so

```cs
public void PrintAnswer(Answer theAnswer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(theAnswer());
    // If 'theAnswer' can be null, then you can check for it normally, or use the Invoke method like so
    Console.WriteLine(theAnswer?.Invoke());
}
```

For convenience .NET includes some pre defined delegate types, namely [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0) which is a method with no return value (void) and an arbitrary amount of parameters (max 16), [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) which is a method with a return type and an arbitrary amount of parameters (up to 16) and last but not least [Predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-6.0) which is a method that returns a boolean and has exactly one parameter (so shorthand for `Func<T, bool>`)

In your case, you'll want to use `Func<string>` like so:

```cs
Func<string> randomPasswordProvider = () => "sekrit";
var randomPassword = randomPasswordProvider(); // or .Invoke()
```

Note that in C# we use a fat arrow (`=>`) for anonymous methods. You could also make the `randomPasswordProvider` point to a "full fat" method like so:

```
string GenerateRandomPassword()
{
    return "Hello world";
}

// Note the lack of '()', we're not invoking the method, only referencing it
Func<string> randomPasswordProvider = GenerateRandomPassword;
```

If you want to name your delegate type, you can easily do it like so:

```cs
public delegate string StringSupplier(); // any name you want

// or, if you want to have it generic:

public delegate T Supplier<out T>(); // the 'out' is not needed but helpful
```

I made an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RKmUxn)

You could then add also add an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to your custom delegate type so you can call `Get()` instead of `Invoke()` or just `()` (but this really isn't necessary, just makes it look more like your Java example)

Answer (score 1):

Any generic [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-delegates) with the "*take no argument, return `T`*" signature will work.
You can define yours:

```
public delegate T Supplier<out T>(); // out is not mandatory but is helpfull
```

Or use [`System.Func<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-6.0) which is declared in the standard library.

To call it, you just use the `()` operator:

```
// Func<string> randomPasswordSupplier = () => "secret";
Supplier<string> randomPasswordSupplier = () => "secret";
stringrandomPassword = randomPasswordSupplier();
```

Answer (score 1):

As [madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665003/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-util-function-supplier#comment124921300_70665003) already noted in a comment, the equivalent is for most cases [`Func<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1). C# doesn't use interfaces for this, but *delegates*, which are effectively the signature of a method.

You can also create your own delegate that does the same:

```
public delegate TResult Supplier<TResult>();
```

This would allow you to include specific documentation for example, where the generic `Func` delegate would be confusing.